# Simple async/await example possible in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I want the asynchronous checkbox, but it doesn't work. I'm using pyautogui and tkinter, I want it to be in a loop by clicking when I find the image, but when I uncheck the checkbox it stops.
Follow the code below:

```
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
import asyncio

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Test')
window.geometry('100x100')

l = tk.Label(window, bg='white', width=20, text='empty')
l.pack()
    
var1 = tk.IntVar()

async def test():
    while (var1.get() == 1):
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('image.png')
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        l.config(text='x= ' + str(x) + ' y= ' + str(y))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='On/Off',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=test)
c1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```